# Problem assigning variable per environment in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, packer, ansible-inventory

I'm building an AMI with packer and providing it with Ansible. The AMI needs to be build with different variables depending on the environment.Therefore I used the below structure based on [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-multistage-environments-with-ansible) article:

```
├── ansible.cfg
├── bamboo-server-dev.yml
├── environments
├── group_vars
│   ├── bamboo_packer_dev.yml
│   └── bamboo_packer_prod.yml
└── roles/
    ├── bamboo-server/
    │   └── vars/
    │       ├── bamboo-dev.yml
    │       ├── bamboo-prod.yml
    │       └── main.yml
    └── ubuntu-server/
```

My environment file is where I define my inventory and looks like this:

```
[bamboo_packer_dev]
localhost

[bamboo_packer_prod]
localhost
```

The group_vars/bamboo_packer_dev.yml looks like the below:

```
---
# Setup specific variables per environment

environment: "dev"
```

The playbook bamboo-server-dev.yml looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: bamboo_packer_dev
  become: true
  roles:
    - ubuntu-server
    - bamboo-server
```

And finally the roles/bamboo-server/vars/main.yml looks like this:

```
---
# Provide variables according to the environment

- name: provide variables
  include_vars:
    file: "bamboo-{{ environment }}.yml"
```

But when I run the playbook I get the following message:

```
ERROR! failed to combine variables, expected dicts but got a 'dict' and a 'AnsibleSequence':
{}
[{"name": "provide variables", "include_vars": {"file": "bamboo-{{ environment }}.yml"}}]
```

It seems the "environment" variable is not getting picked up. And I cannot figure it why. Can someone please suggest what might be wrong with my playbook? Or abetter way to achieve this? My Ansible version is 2.9.1 running on Mojave.

Comment: my 0.02$: I'd bet the error is in your playbook that you did not post. run yamllint and ansible-lint against all your files.

Comment: Hello thanks for your help, I've already ran the linters against al my files as you suggested and had some minor errors like, trailing spaces, line too long and no new line character at the end of file mainly. I've corrected all those just in case, but still get the same error. Anything else I can check?

Comment: If `ansible-lint` didn't catch that `vars` file being malformed, then it's a bug in `ansible-lint`

Answer (score 1):

Your `vars` file cannot include ansible tasks, as you have done. Files in `vars` must be -- as ansible very clearly informed you -- `dict` and not `list`, since the keys of the `vars` file becomes variable names, and `[]` is not a variable name

Perhaps you meant to put that content into `roles/bamboo-server/tasks/main.yml`, which will allow you to have `include_vars:` as an action